# LINQ Contains weird behaviour

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, contains

I have managed to develop my first MVC 5 web application with CRUD functionality.

My data has got few ways to search through the records, but one of them doesn't seem to do what I expect it to do. Here's my controller search query code:

```
query = query.Where(c =>
        c.PostCode.Contains(searchString)
        || c.Place1.Select(e => e.PostCode).Contains(searchString)
```

Here's my model:

```
public Place()
    {
        Place1 = new HashSet<Place>();
    }

    [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Place> Place1 { get; set; }
```

My database relationship is a self referencing table -> 1 to 0, hence same name for the fields.

Could anyone explain me why the search function will bring expected results when searching for the full value "NR32 4TW" for both parts of the code, but only the first query part (Before OR operator) of the search will find the same record if I'll do a partial search using "NR32 4T"?

I have checked the query against other fields within the database and they have the same problem.

**TDLR;**
LINQ ".Contains()" doesn't search for the parts of the string when using it on a Collection within the model. Could anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: LINQ is an interface. Are you using Entity Framework? That is what implements the LINQ interface.

Comment: You are mixing `Enumerable.Contains` with `string.Contains`. The second criteria should be `c.Practice1.Any(e => e.PostCode.Contains(searchString))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>not taking into account that you have a difference .... Practice1 and Place1</strike>

you are using 2 different functions with the name "Contains"

```
c.PostCode.Contains(searchString)
```

this is `String.Contains(string)` ... it looks for the parameter in the string you are calling it on...

```
c.Practice1.Select(e => e.PostCode).Contains(searchString)
```

this is `IEnumerable<string>.Contains(string)` ... it looks for a string in an enumeration of strings ...

what you wanted to do is most likely this:

```
c.PostCode.Contains(searchString) || c.Practice1.Any(e => e.PostCode.Contains(searchString))
```

Comment: I have made adjustment to the code to reflect your comment in the first line. Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Contains()` is searching a sequence (list) to see if the exact value is in it. It's not searching text.

Comment: PostCode is a string. If its EF then Contains call should be translated into LIKE

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy If you call `Contains` on a `string`, then yes, you're asking if that string contains a sub-string.  If you call `Contains` *on a set of values* you're asking if the value is in the set, not of the value is a substring of a value in the set.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy And that's exactly why he said it works fine for the first part of the OR statement but not the second. The second part is a sequence: `c.Place1.Select(e => e.PostCode).Contains(searchString)`

Comment: @JoePhillips my bad  - didn't notice second *contains* here

Answer (score 1):

You want to search the string values of each `PostCode` for the partial value, your code however searches the list of post codes for the full value of the search. The difference is where you put your closing brackets.

```
c.Practice1.Select(e => e.PostCode).Contains(searchString)
```

vs

```
c.Practice1.Select(e => e.PostCode.Contains(searchString))
```

By using the latter goes through the string of each `PostCode` and matches that string contains `searchString`, the former selects all `PostCode`s then looks for a match in that list of post codes to the exact `searchString`.